# Have multiple JSON fields named in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm building a class that will be exposed to third party developers where I want to expose things with enums but also keep a raw copy for them to use if needed.

I am using GSON and I was wondering if there was a way to include the same field twice?

```java
    public enum Error { GENERIC, EVIL, GOOD };

    public static class A {
        @SerializedName("error")
        Error error = Error.GENERIC;
        @SerializedName("error")
        String rawError;
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultipleFields() {
        A a = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson("{\"error\":\"100\"}", A.class);
        assertThat(a.rawError).isEqualTo("100");
        assertThat(a.error).isEqualTo(Error.GENERIC);
    }
```

When I run this I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class ParseUtilTest$A declares multiple JSON fields named error
```

Is there any way to allow this to happen?

Comment: You might want to reformulate your question. I think this is a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/374140). So start with an example  what you actually mean by *I want to keep a raw copy of specfic values in my models.*. The input and the output.

Answer (score -1):

No. Gson will throw an IllegalArgumentException that will tell you that a certain class declares multiple JSON fields with the same name 'YES'.